# unable to install 18.04.2 with ext. graphics

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, graphics, amd-ryzen

My specs: ryzen 2200g with internal Vega graphics,
asrock 320m hdv,
geforce 750ti external graphics.
Lts 18.04.2 written to Usb disk. I want to install ubuntu near win 10.
When I switch Primary video option to external graphics in BIOS, it is unable to start installation process with black screen showing errors. When switch to internal graphics adapter - everything is fine. Installation is completed and system working well. When switch back to external and start the system its crashing again.
**The question is - how should I install and run Ubuntu with 750Ti as main videoadapter? Any suggestions? Please, help :`(**

CSM enabled;
'nomodeset' tried - splash screen loop;

[Bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFr4U.jpg)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGt3V.jpg)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN9vt.jpg)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqJzf.jpg)

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: How can I do that without installed system?

Comment: You wrote "When switch to internal graphics adapter - everything is fine". So install it that way, then install drivers (not from a .run file!!!), then switch the adapter. And you don't need to enable CSM, or use `nomodeset`.

Comment: hey Dmitry K. I've got a buddy with the same kind of problem as you, it's due to the new Hardware cpu (ATI) and graphics (AMD) card not being supported by ubuntu 18.04.2 (yet?) he solved it by switching to ubuntu 18.10 I also switched to ubuntu 18.10 but originally because I wanted a more recent version of wine and then I found out the newer kernel also fixed hibernation which had not been working for me ad correctly detecting xbox controllers I had an issue with 18.04.2. anyways you should try 18.10 and maybe also upgrade the kernel even further when you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things that solved this problem:

- download and write 18.10 ubuntu
- update BIOS to 5.5 (from 4.6) (using integrated video to avoid problems)
- reset BIOS settings
- switch primary video to external in AMD PBS settings, switch monitor cable, reboot
- when boot from USB press any key and chose to try Ubuntu and install it from this subsystem
- boot from disk, install proprietary drivers, done